# Running Windows-compiled C++ program on Linux machine using Runtime

Tags: java, linux, runtime

I need to run an executable on the command line through Java. I have seen a lot of information about this and using the `Runtime` object to execute the file. However I have a problem: the executable is written in C++ and compiled for Windows, but I'm using Linux. I have no access to the source code.

I read in the documentation of the `Runtime` environment that

> Runtime that allows the application to interface with the environment in which the application is running

The environment I am running it on is Linux, so the application would not work if the application is interfacing with my Linux environment.

I am curious if there are any other objects other than `Runtime` that could do this, but mimic the runtime of a different OS. For example maybe a `WindowsRuntime` object or something that you could call and have the application run without having to recompile it for Linux. It seems like this could be pretty complicated (perhaps like a virtual machine) but thought it was worth a try.

Comment: I'm confused. So is your C++ program compiled for Windows then? If so, couldn't you just compile it for Linux?

Comment: Yes its compiled for Windows, but I am not the one who wrote the code and I would like the users of my program to not have to worry about that either

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear from the question. I've made an edit to make this very obvious to future readers.

Comment: About the only thing that'll run a Win32 C++ program in Linux, is something like WINE.